# TCP open socket delay

Tags: sockets, tcp, connect

What is the time consumed in order to open a TCP socket with remote server? For example, in C, How long does it take from the time of calling `connect()` function until the time it returns with 0?
What are the factors affecting this time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major factor affecting this is the time needed for the [initial TCP handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) which mostly depends on how far away (in terms on network, i.e hops and duration) the peer is. Other factors like performance of the system are mostly irrelevant as long as neither client nor server starving on resources (i.e. DOS attack).